# Landscape standalone server 18.03 on Ubuntu 18.04: cannot sync pocket from demo (gpg certs missing?)

Tags: 18.04, landscape

I'm trying to set up a Landscape standalone server on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (for a demonstration at this point).

I have tried to set up the repository per these instructions: https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/user-guide/ch09.html

I get to the point where we sync the pocket that we've set up (the only deviation from the instructions provided is that I'm using bionic as the release and amd64 as the architecture).

Unfortunately, at this point, the sync doesn't succeed, as the result of the `landscape-api get-activities --query id:<id returned from sync-mirror-pocket instruction>` returns the following:

```
"ERROR: Condition '40976EAF437D05B5' not fulfilled for './lists/update-bionic_bionic_InRelease'.
Signatures in './lists/update-bionic_bionic_InRelease':
'3B4FE6ACC0B21F32' (signed 2018-04-26): missing pubkey
Error: Not enough signatures found for remote repository update-bionic (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic)!
There have been errors!"
```

Initially, upon encountering this error, I downloaded the gpg key with the ID shown in the 'Condition' portion of message from the Ubuntu mirror, and installed it into the Landscape gpg key cache with a landscape-api import-gpg-key command (which succeeded). However, this did not solve the problem, and the condition persists.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my own problem.

Steps: first, use gpg to download the key with the missing public key ID (from above-'3B4FE6ACC0B21F32') from Ubuntu's key server (directions on verifying the identity of an Ubuntu image will have directions on that).  Then, use gpg to export the key to a .pem file.

Next, import the key into the landscape API keychain, using landscape-api import-gpg-key.  I named mine "ubuntu-bionic-public-key-2".

Finally, (and this part really needs to be added to the documentation that I originally referenced): do the following:

```
# landscape-api edit-pocket --mirror-gpg-key ubuntu-bionic-public-key-2 release bionic ubuntu
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out. I've reported a bug (LP#1810793) to have the new mirror key added or documented.