# Import ubuntu public key into landscape

Tags: 18.04, landscape

[Landscape standalone server 18.03 on Ubuntu 18.04: cannot sync pocket from demo (gpg certs missing?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106362/landscape-standalone-server-18-03-on-ubuntu-18-04-cannot-sync-pocket-from-demo)

I found the above issue on this site that describes my problem almost exactly, and provides a solution, but I can't get the gpg key imported into landscape with the "edit-pocket" command. I receive a "server error 500". The gpg commands weren't specified.

Can someone clarify the commands to receive and export the gpg keys from Ubuntu?
These are what I tried, and the error I received:

```
# gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
# gpg -a --export 790BC7277767219C42C86F933B4FE6ACC0B21F32 > /tmp/ubuntu-bionic-public-key-2
# landscape-api edit-pocket --mirror-gpg-key /tmp/ubuntu-bionic-public-key-2 release bionic ubuntu
Got unexpected server error:
Status: 500
Error message: Server error
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had skipped the import-gpg-key step, and was specifying the filename in the edit-pocket command, instead of the key name.

The following commands worked for me to add the key and get the pockets to sync:

```
# gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
# gpg -a --export 790BC7277767219C42C86F933B4FE6ACC0B21F32 > /tmp/ubuntu-bionic-public-key-2
# landscape-api import-gpg-key ubuntu-bionic-public-key-2  /tmp/ubuntu-bionic-public-key-2
# landscape-api edit-pocket --mirror-gpg-key ubuntu-bionic-public-key-2 release bionic ubuntu
```