# Cannot get 22.04 to mirror on landscape

Tags: landscape, 22.04

Having issues getting 22.04 to sync to landscape server running 19.10. the series successfully adds using this command as root:

landscape-api create-series --pockets release,updates,security,backports --components main,restricted,universe,multiverse --architectures amd64,i386 --mirror-gpg-key zesty-key --gpg-key secret-key --mirror-uri http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ --mirror-series jammy jammy ubuntu

but when i try to sync manually using **landscape-api sync-mirror-pocket release jammy ubuntu** i get this error:

***ERROR: Condition '3B4FE6ACC0B21F32+' not fulfilled for './lists/update-jammy_jammy_InRelease'.
Signatures in './lists/update-jammy_jammy_InRelease':
'871920D1991BC93C' (signed 2022-04-21): missing pubkey
Error: Not enough signatures found for remote repository update-jammy (http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy)!
There have been errors!***

I have looked through other threads on here and around other sites and it has suggested downloading a key from keyserver.ubuntu.com, but this is not applicable for my situation unfortunately.

The server was updated after it failed the first time and the series has been removed and re-added several times since then. The key originally didn't have a hash but it does now

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: I have the same behaviour on a fresh installation of landscape. I'm able to sync bionic repos but not jammy with exact same error.

Answer (score 2):

Here where i found the inspiration to solve this problem: [Import ubuntu public key into landscape](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188190/import-ubuntu-public-key-into-landscape)

First take the up to date key landscape complain to

```
gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
```

After that export the public key

```
gpg -a --export F6ECB3762474EDA9D21B7022871920D1991BC93C > ubuntu-jammy-public-key-2
```

Import the key in landscape

```
landscape-api import-gpg-key jammy-mirror ubuntu-jammy-public-key-2
```

Import it in the pockets

```
landscape-api edit-pocket --mirror-gpg-key jammy-mirror release jammy ubuntu
landscape-api edit-pocket --mirror-gpg-key jammy-mirror updates jammy ubuntu
landscape-api edit-pocket --mirror-gpg-key jammy-mirror security jammy ubuntu
```

After this the sync command do not complain anymore and download correctly the packages

```
  ....
  u'id': 72,
  u'modification_time': u'2022-05-05T09:52:59Z',
  u'parent_id': 71,
  u'pocket_id': 32,
  u'pocket_name': u'release',
  u'progress': 3,
  ....
```